# Duas ViewModels em uma View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

estou com um problema, vamos a explicação:

Possuo uma pagina chamada `Index` aonde renderizo todos os `clientes` do meu banco de dados em uma tabela, nessa tabela existem um botão de excluir que abre um `Modal de Confirmação` que cria um `Form` com um campo `Hidden`, a minha duvida é, como posso utilizar as `ViewModels` de `IndexClientViewModel` e `DeleteClientViewModel`, sendo que são na mesma pagina, pois hoje quando tento deletar, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
FormatException: TODO: Malformed input.

InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
```

Acredito que o `1º Erro`, seja por causa do ViewModel, e o segundo seja um problema gerado pelo `1º Erro`,

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@model X.PagedList.StaticPagedList<ApplicationClient>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Clientes";
}

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var cliente in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <h6>
                         <small class="text-muted">
                             <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                         </small>
                         <a href="#"> @cliente.Nome</a>
                     </h6>
                     <small class="text-muted">
                         <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                          @foreach (var telefones in cliente.ClientesTelefone)
                          {
                          <span>-</span> @Html.DisplayFor(model => telefones.Telefone)
                          }
                     </small>
                     <br />
                     <small class="text-muted">
                         <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                         @foreach (var emails in cliente.ClientesEmail)
                         {
                             <span>-</span> @Html.DisplayFor(model => emails.Email)
                         }
                     </small>
                </td>
                <td><span class="label label-success">Ativo</span></td>
                <td class="text-nowrap">
                    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target=".editClient" data-id="@cliente.Id">
                        <button class="btn btn-transparent" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Editar"> 
                             <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target=".deleteClient" data-client="@cliente.Id" data-name="@cliente.Nome">
                         <button class="btn btn-transparent" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Excluir"> 
                             <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> 
                         </button>
                   </span>
               </td>
          </tr>
   }
   </tbody>
```

`Modal Confirmação que está na pagina Index`:

```
<div class="modal fade deleteClient" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteClientLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteClientLabel"></h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li>* Não será possível desfazer esta exclusão;</li>
                <li>* Não será possível acessar aos dados deste cliente;</li>
                <li>* Os agendamentos para este cliente serão excluidos do sistema;</li>
            </ul>
            <form asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Client" id="deleteClientForm">
                <input name="Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="clientDelete">
            </form>
            <br />
            <span class="text-error"><b>Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse cliente ?</b></span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('#deleteClientForm').submit();">Excluir</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(DeleteClientViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        var client = await _clientManager.GetClientId(model.Id);

        if (client == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o cliente com o ID '{client.Id}'.");
        }

        var result = await _clientManager.DeleteClientAsync(client);

        TempData["MensagemSucesso"] = "Cliente deletado com sucesso";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

`DeleteClientViewModel`:

```
public class DeleteClientViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

`Javascript`:

```
$('.deleteClient').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
var id = button.data('client');
var name = button.data('name'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
// If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
// Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-title').text('Excluir Cliente: '  + name)
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(id)
```

});

Comment: Crie uma nova que declare as duas e trabalhe com ela... Mas o erro não tem a ver com isso... Inclua a controller na pergunta e se você não está implementando, não utiliza a anotação do AntiforgeryTokenValidation

Comment: Onde está o código do post?

Comment: Adicionei mais dados na pergunta @Leandro Angelo

Comment: Remova o `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, o post é só o submit? quantos ids deleteClientForm você tem na tela?

Comment: Faço o Post, pela Model que coloquei na pergunta

Comment: Só um Id, coloco através de um `Javascript`, coloquei na pergunta também

Comment: Removeu o `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`?

Comment: Removi sim, agora estou conseguindo enviar perfeitamente, só esta acontecendo alguns outros erros,  mas teria alguma forma de manter o `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` ?

Comment: Inspecionando o formulário, você viu se o razor criou um hidden `__RequestVerificationToken` ?

Comment: Criou o campo hidden sim

Comment: Então infelizmente eu não consigo reproduzir o seu problema

Comment: resolveu esse problema?